# How do I make my display a dual-screen stretch with Debian Jessie and a Radeon RX460?

Tags: debian, display, display-settings, amd-graphics

I am running Debian 8.2 Jessie with an AMD Radeon RX 460. MATE is my desktop environment. I use two monitors.

Anything on Monitor 1 is displayed on Monitor 2. I want instead for Monitor 2 to be like an extension of Monitor 1, as you would see in many monitor setups.

Is this possible with Debian 8.2 and my RX 460?

**Edit**

Output of running `xrandr -q` in MATE Terminal:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00* 
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux desktop 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Look into ARandR. might help

Comment: @jc__ Hm, the GUI does not seem to detect the second monitor...

Comment: Since you are running Debian, there is a good chance you are running Gnome. If so the simplest thing to try is running `gnome-control-center display` and see if that sees your two displays.

Comment: @icarus That package does not show up in the list of packages I can install. I'm using MATE desktop environment rather than GNOME.

Comment: OK, I am out of my depth, so this is just generic advice until someone who can help comes along. Can you run `xrandr -q`? If so can you add the output to the question? What we are aiming for are the names of the outputs of the RX 460, and then we can try telling it to drive them separately. Probably `Mate` will have a pretty gui to drive this, but let me try and help via a cli.

Comment: Output of `uname -a`? I was expecting rather different output from xrandr.

Comment: @icarus added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49274/discussion-between-icarus-and-username).

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Same issue here with a Radeon R7 240, two HDMI outputs. Kernel 4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 and free driver. Same xrandr output. Only one screen detected so I can only get a clone and even then, I have to pick a 1280/1024 (5:4) resolution for the video projector, and the display on the 16:10-ish monitor is stretched. The issue is that only one display is detected even after clicking "detect monitors" in the "Monitors" GUI.

Comment: I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99337

Comment: Did not find a fix yet. I was told to upgrade to Debian Stretch, but when I did, the system would not boot up to where I could log in

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it appeared ([bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99337)) it was due to the fact that the proprietary binary-only firmware was not installed on my system.

That firmware ships with `firmware-linux-nonfree`. I installed that package ([RMS](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vrms) won't be proud anymore...) and now it works.

See Debian wiki about [radeon proprietary firmware](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Firmware).

Comment: Installing that package did nothing for me

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Still relevant to you in the bug report : 'Output name "default" means you're not using the radeon driver but some kind of generic fallback driver.' You may want to check your Xorg log and dmesg output to figure out what is wrong. Do you still get the same xrandr output?

Comment: I'd like to keep this answer here anyway as it may help someone with the same symptoms: it would have saved myself some time and I wouldn't have wasted the developers time with a wrong bug report.

Comment: I get the same `xrandr` output

Comment: Weird. It would mean you have the firmware installed but not loaded? From the answer I had on the bugtracker, I suggest you edit your question with Xorg log and dmesg output.